# Return class name and access it from $this afterwards in php

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Hello i am building an application and want to do something similar to codeigniter.

I have a Controller class:

```
class Controller{

    function __construct(){
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->load = new Loader();
    }
}
```

My Loader class:

```
class Loader{

    function __construct(){
        echo 'Loader Class Instanciated';
    }

    public function model($model){
        $file = 'models/' . $model . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            $this->model = new $model();
            return $this->model;
        }
    }
}
```

and my Help Controller class:

```
class Help extends Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->render('index/index');
    }

    public function other(){
        $model = $this->load->model('Help_Model');
        $model->meth();
    }
}
```

So far everything works. But i would like to have something like:

```
$this->load->model('Help_Model');
$this->Help_Model->meth();
```

How would that be possible? It gives me an error of Undefined variable Help::$Help_Model() when i try to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining it as $model not Help_Model. In your loader class do something like the below. Haven't used PHP in a while but I hope that helps.

```
$this->{$model} = new $model();
```

Then in help do

```
$this->load->model('Help_Model'); 
$this->load->Help_Model->meth();
```

Comment: no i still get the error Notice: Undefined property: Help::$Help_Model

Comment: There's no need to return the model and also define the return in Help. 
Just do 
        $this->load->model('Help_Model');
        $this->load->Help_Model->meth();

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it like this:

Added this function to controller class so that i can access the controller instance.

```
public static function getInstance($controller){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new $controller;
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
```

and then i modified the loader class like:

```
public function model($model){
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $controller = Controller::getInstance($url[0]);
        $file = 'models/' . $model . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            $controller->{$model} = new $model();
            log_message('INFO', 'Model: ' . $model . ' loaded successfully');
            return $controller->{$model};
        }
    }
```

and then it worked as such:

```
$this->load->model('Help_Model');
$this->Help_Model->meth();
```

I hope it helps someone with such kind of problemm